# RAbbitMQ: How to stop consume, channel, and connection when the queue is empty using EventBasicConsumer

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq

We have some queues, with same number of error queues.

My boss asked me to write a Window Service to consume the error queues, and transfer the data to DB.
The Windows Service should be capable of managing which queues should be consumed, based on configurations set in DB table, this means for example that if I want not to consume a specific queue anymore,
I must be able to disable the configuration for that specific queue on DB, without stop the Window Service.

I planned to write a Windows Service Job scheduled with help fo Quartz, the Job at every schedule should read the DB configuration, open a single connection,
launch tasks for all the queues to consume, consumes the queues with a single channel per task. With this solution I hope to solve because at the end of the task channels will be closed,
connection will be closed, error queues will be consumed, and in the next job schedule the number and the name of queue to read could be different.
Also, consuming all the messages per single queues at every schedule shuld save the opening/closing connection/channel that could be onerous if I consume a single message per schedule,
so the time of schedule should be enough to consume all error messages in queue, before next schedule.
Also, scheduling the queues will give me the chance to configure the queues to consume in DB, without the need of stop the Windows Service.

Now I wrote a bit of code to test the solution of consume the single queue

```
var consumer = new QueueingBasicConsumer(channel);
channel.BasicConsume(queueParName, autoAck: false, consumer: consumer);
bool queueEmpty = false;
while (!queueEmpty)
{
    try
        BasicDeliverEventArgs result;
        bool bRead = consumer.Queue.Dequeue(timeOutQueueEmpty, out result);

        if (bRead)
        {
            var msgBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result.Body);
            // TO DB ...
        }
        else
        {
            queueEmpty = true;
        }
    }
    catch (EndOfStreamException ex)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The problem is **QueueingBasicConsumer** is obsolete and in many places is written to prefear **EventBasicConsumer**

```
var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
{
    var body = ea.Body;
    var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);

    // TO DB...
};
channel.BasicConsume(queue: queueParName, autoAck: true, consumer: consumer);
```

But with EventBasicConsumer I can't understand how to stop the consume when the  queue is empty in order to cloes connection and channel

EDIT

A little bit of deeper explanation, as asked in the comment.
It would be difficult to put all the code here, because we use a lot of compiled libraries of our company, so the code would be not completely understandable.
Anyway, simplifing:

1. I have an Host project, in which use Quartz Package to schedule a Job every N time.

...

```
var schedule = SimpleScheduleBuilder.Create();
schedule.WithIntervalInSeconds(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["..."]);
schedule.RepeatForever();
s.ScheduleQuartzJob(q =>
    q.WithJob(() =>
        JobBuilder.Create<RabbitErrorDequeuerJob>().Build())
            .AddTrigger(() =>
                TriggerBuilder.Create()
                    .WithSchedule(schedule)
                    .Build())
);
```

...

have Ninject IOC, and in Module file I inject the connection

```
// *** Ninject disposes every Disposable object that has another scope other than InTransientScope
Bind<IConnection>().ToMethod(x =>
{
IConnectionFactory cnf = new ConnectionFactory();
cnf.Uri = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["..."]);
return cnf.CreateConnection();
}).InCallScope();
```

I have a Job project, scheduled by Quartz every N Time, in which I have the Execute method (Quartz.IJob interface)

```
 public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            List<RabbitQueueConfiguration> lst = //...LIST OF QUEUTE TO DEQUE FROM DATABASE
            foreach (RabbitQueueConfiguration queue in lst)
            {
                Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    DequeuSingleQueue(queue);
                });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _log.FatalFormat("Error ", ex.Message);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

In DequeuSingleQueue(queue) there is the core of dequeuing

Comment: Can you narrow this down a bit? Your channel/connection/consumer have to be managed outside of the logic that processes and individual message. What code do you have to start/stop that?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`BasicGet`](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dotnet-api-guide.html#basic-get) to process messages one-at-a-time.

Comment: thank for the advice @Luke Bakken, I evalued BasicGet, it'would be the clearer way, but I'm warried about using a new connection (with open and close connection) for every scheduled job, since all scheduled job will read only one message, I will be bound about to set the job to schedule more frequent. I'm not sure, but I read somewhere that open and close connection repeatly could be onerous, that's way I wanted to dequeue the entire queue at every schedule, and schedule it with a not short span between one schedule and another.

Comment: Why can't you open a connection and channel, execute `BasicGet` until no more messages remain, then close the channel and connection?

Comment: The answer is because maybe I'm just a little too focused on the method of dequeue all messages at once (and maybe I'm just a bit dummy)
... Actually as you say I could cycle on BasicGet, until it returns null ... think it can be a good practice? can there be contraindications? Performance?

Comment: Just read here rabbitmq.com/dotnet-api-guide.html about BasicGet, "Note that fetching messages using this API is relatively inefficient.". The advice is "Retrieving Messages By Subscription ("push API")" --> consumer.Received += (ch, ea) => { ...

Comment: Unless you are processing hundreds or thousands of messages per second, don't worry about the performance. You should *always* benchmark using your expected workload to ensure your code meets expectations.